# Added data doesn't show after program ended

Tags: c++

When I try to add data and display, it works fine. But when I end the program and try to display it, the data that is added previously doesn't show up in the list that is displayed. It just shows 15 cars like the first time I display it

```
//Running the program for the first time, adding and displaying data works fine, but after I ended 
//the program and display it again, the data that was added previously doesn't show up on the list.


#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
//a struct of antique cars
struct antique_cars
{
    //unsigned int no;
    string name;
    string manufacturer;
    unsigned int year;
    float price;
};
string name;
string manufacturer;
unsigned int year;
float price;
//create an array of struct
antique_cars car[20];
int carCount = 15;

//function to display cars
void display()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= carCount; i++)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << car[i].name << endl;
        cout << "Manufactured by: " << car[i].manufacturer << endl;
        cout << "Manufactured in: " << car[i].year << endl;
        cout << "Price: "
             << "$" << car[i].price << " million" << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

I can add data here and display it while the program is running, but after it ends the added data here disappear

```
//function to add cars
void addCar()
{
    int cars_to_be_added = 0;
    cout << "How many cars do you want to add?" << endl;
    cin >> cars_to_be_added;
    if (cars_to_be_added != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 16; i < (16 + cars_to_be_added); i++)
        {
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Enter car's name: ";
            getline(cin, car[i].name);
            cout << "Enter car's manufacturer: ";
            cin >> car[i].manufacturer;
            cout << "Enter the year it was made: ";
            cin >> car[i].year;
            cout << "Enter the car's price: ";
            cin >> car[i].price;
        }
        carCount++;
        cout << "Car(s) added" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No cars will be added.";
    }
}
```

I stored all the data in int main

```
int main()
{
    //data of car 1-15
    car[1] =
        {
            //car[1].no = 1,
            car[1].name = "Ferrari 250 LM",
            car[1].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[1].year = 1964,
            car[1].price = 17.6};

    car[2] =
        {
            //car[2].no = 2,
            car[2].name = "Ferrari 250 GT LWB California Spider Competizione",
            car[2].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[2].year = 1959,
            car[2].price = 18.15};
    car[3] =
        {
            //car[3].no = 3,
            car[3].name = "McLaren F1 LM",
            car[3].manufacturer = "McLaren",
            car[3].year = 1994,
            car[3].price = 19.8};
    car[4] =
        {
            //car[4].no = 4,
            car[4].name = "Ferrari 250 GT SWB California Spider",
            car[4].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[4].year = 1961,
            car[4].price = 20};
    car[5] =
        {
            //car[5].no =5,
            car[5].name = "Alfa Romeo 8C 2900B Lungo Spider",
            car[5].manufacturer = "Alfa Romeo",
            car[5].year = 1939,
            car[5].price = 21.23};
    car[6] =
        {
            //car[6].no = 6,
            car[6].name = "Aston Martin DP215",
            car[6].manufacturer = "Aston Martin",
            car[6].year = 1963,
            car[6].price = 21.45};
    car[7] =
        {
            //car[7].no = 7,
            car[7].name = "Duesenberg SSJ",
            car[7].manufacturer = "Duesenberg",
            car[7].year = 1935,
            car[7].price = 22};
    car[8] =
        {
            //car[8].no = 8,
            car[8].name = "Jaguar D-Type",
            car[8].manufacturer = "Jaguar",
            car[8].year = 1955,
            car[8].price = 23.25};
    car[9] =
        {
            //car[9].no = 9,
            car[9].name = "Aston Martin DBR1",
            car[9].manufacturer = "Aston Martin",
            car[9].year = 1949,
            car[9].price = 23.67};
    car[10] =
        {
            //car[10].no = 10,
            car[10].name = "Ferrari 275 GTB/C Speciale",
            car[10].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[10].year = 1964,
            car[10].price = 28.70};
    car[11] =
        {
            //car[11].no = 11,
            car[11].name = "Ferrari 275 GTB/4S NART Spider",
            car[11].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[11].year = 1967,
            car[11].price = 30.38};
    car[12] =
        {
            //car[12].no = 12,
            car[12].name = "Ferrari 290 MM",
            car[12].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[12].year = 1956,
            car[12].price = 30.45};
    car[13] =
        {
            //car[13].no = 13,
            car[13].name = "Mercedes-Benz W196",
            car[13].manufacturer = "Mercedez-Benz",
            car[13].year = 1954,
            car[13].price = 32.17};
    car[14] =
        {
            //car[14].no = 14,
            car[14].name = "Ferrari 335 S Spider",
            car[14].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[14].year = 1957,
            car[14].price = 38.30};
    car[15] =
        {
            //car[15].no = 15,
            car[15].name = "Ferrari GTO",
            car[15].manufacturer = "Ferrari",
            car[15].year = 1962,
            car[15].price = 48.40};
    car[16] =                    
        {
            car[16].name,
            car[16].manufacturer,
            car[16].year,
            car[16].price};
    char choice;
    bool again;
    do
    {
        int input;
        cout << "Enter 1 to display cars \n";
        cout << "Enter 2 to add cars \n";
        cin >> input;
        cin.ignore();
        switch (input)
        {
        case 1:
        {
            display();
        }
        break;
        case 2:
        {
            addCar();
        }
        break;
        default:
        {
            cout << "Option unavailable \n";
        }
        }
        cout << "Do you want to run the program again? \n";
        cin >> choice;
        if (choice == 'n' || choice == 'N')
        {
            cout << "Thank you" << endl;
            again = false;
        }
        else
        {
            again = true;
        }
    } while (again == true);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there is `i <= carCount` in loop `for` in `display()`. And the global variable `int carCount = 15;`. So, your program outputs 15 elements.

Answer (score 0):

carCount +=  cars_to_be_added instead of carCount++
And modify cars starting index as 0 instead of 1

Answer (score 0):

Addcar if condition

If( cars_to_be_added > 0 &&
( (cars_to_be_added + carCount) < 20)
)